# Best way to consume kafka messages and send them to websocket clients by filter the client sends

Tags: websocket, apache-kafka, apache-nifi

I want to send messages from kafka to clients through a websocket,
I have kafka topic of with json records like:  `{...fields...., type:1}`.

A client initiates the connection to websocket with a json message that includes an array field of the types he intrested in like: `{...fields..., types:[1,3,4]}`

I tried to do it with Nifi but I dont have a way to consume from kafka and at the same time filter the messages that I get by the type.

I would be happy to get recommandations on a way of doing this in Nifi or any other way (Streamsets, implementing costumized websocket that consumes from kafka etc...)

(My code is written in java)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> with Nifi but I dont have a way to consume from kafka and at the same time filter the messages that I get by the type

ConsumeKafka + [RecordPath filter](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/record-path-guide.html#filters) *should work* fine...

---

Alternatively, you have not mentioned what type of system your webserver is running...

You would [write it in Spring Boot](https://dzone.com/articles/live-dashboard-using-apache-kafka-and-spring-webso)... [or Django](https://dzone.com/articles/supercharging-kafka-enable-realtime-web-streaming), ... or Flask+Faust, [or NodeJS](https://medium.com/@stressed83/live-streaming-data-using-kafka-node-js-websocket-and-chart-js-8750acad549c) then forward Kafka messages from a built-in consumer to a web-socket.

**tl;dr** ***Search*** "*your language* + websocket + kafka" ... I'm sure there will be results

---

Or you could use the Kafka REST Proxy, then just use AJAX instead of a WebSocket.

---

You could also use [Kafka Connect HTTP Sink](https://www.confluent.io/blog/webify-event-streams-using-kafka-connect-http-sink) to just send events to an open webhook (such as Nifi's ListenHTTP), for example.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I used kafka connect httpsinkconnector and it worked !
About what you said on nifi..you cant use the listenwebsocket json message on the consumeKafka filter (that was my problem ).

Comment: You could use the `ListenWebSocket` to the `ProduceKafka`, but that seems different than what you asked

Comment: I wanted to take events from kafka and do the ListenWebSocket msg filter on them... but it seems impossible with Nifi...
Thanks again :)

Comment: Right. ListenWebSocket would require a sent HTTP message to it, not a Kafka message